# Use wildcard in python shell rule

Tags: snakemake

I would like to do something like the following in Snakemake:

```
rule RULE:
  input: ...
  output: "{tool}/{file}"
  shell: lambda wildcards: command_for_tool[wildcards.tool]
```

possibly with the shell command wrapped in a `format(.., file=wildcards.file)` to expand the `{file}` that will be inside the `command_for_tool`.

Currently I can do this using a `run:` calling `shell(..)`, but I can't use this because I'm benchmarking the memory usage of the rule and going via python adds `30+MB` overhead.

It is possible to use some python code inside the `shell:` rule that returns a string, but in this case I cannot figure out how to use the wildcards.

It is also possible to use wildcards directly in a string value, where they will be substituted automatically, but this doesn't allow for the map-lookup I need.

Is there a clean solution to this? (Currently I'm trying to work around it using `params:`.) To me it seems like an omission/inconsistency in how snakemake works.

Answer (score 1):

Using your own suggestion, a solution using `params` seems quite clean:

```
rule RULE:
    input:
        'in.txt',
    output:
        '{foo}.txt',
    params:
        cmd= lambda wc: command_for_tool[wc.foo],
    shell:
        """
        {params.cmd} 
        """
```

although I can see that for consistency with the `input` and `params` directive, also `shell: lambda wildcards: command_for_tool[wildcards.tool]` should work.

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I have now, but note that the `shell: "{params.cmd}"` does not do recursive expansion, so you have to manually expand (with `.format()`) wildcards/variables that are part of the command line to be invoked.